# FTP SITE commands supported by IIS servers

Tags: iis, ftp

I've searched and searched but I cannot find a list of FTP SITE commands supported by the IIS 7/8/9 servers, or even a list of FTP commands for that matter. Does anyone know the list of SITE (server specific) commands that IIS supports?? I need it because I'm the author of an [FTP client library](https://github.com/hgupta9/FluentFTP), which needs to support these [server specific commands](https://github.com/hgupta9/FluentFTP/issues/88).

Answer (score 1):

It's easy to [set up an IIS FTP server on any Windows](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/guide_windows_ftps_server) computer and then retrieve list of commands:

```
ftp> remotehelp
214-The following commands are recognized (* ==>'s unimplemented).

ABOR     ENC *    MKD      PWD      SMNT     XMKD 
ACCT     EPRT     MODE     QUIT     STAT     XPWD 
ADAT *   EPSV     NLST     REIN     STOR     XRMD 
ALLO     FEAT     NOOP     REST     STOU 
APPE     HELP     OPTS     RETR     STRU 
AUTH     HOST     PASS     RMD      SYST 
CCC      LANG     PASV     RNFR     TYPE 
CDUP     LIST     PBSZ     RNTO     USER 
CWD      MDTM     PORT     SITE     XCUP 
DELE     MIC *    PROT     SIZE     XCWD 

214 HELP command successful.
```

Here, I reformatted the output to be in columns for better readability. The output is from IIS 10, but as you can see, [Commands Supported by FtpWebRequest and IIS FTP](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/lexli/2009/08/12/commands-supported-by-ftpwebrequest-and-iis-ftp/) has been identical since IIS 7.5.

Comment: Yes but the SITE commands are still not mentioned. Only the command "SITE" as you can see in the listing.

Comment: True. Even `SITE HELP` didn't give any more information and `remotehelp SITE` only gives the correct syntax `SITE - (site-specific command)` without any listing. Dead end. :(

Answer (score 0):

To put this to bed, as of right now IIS FTP handles these SITE commands:

- DIRSTYLE
- HELP
- (or no parameters is treated as HELP)